# Differences in graphs 3D plot with functions

Tags: matlab, wolframalpha

I have this function:

[image]

In WolframAlpha this is the Graph:

[image: Wolfram]

And in MatLab I use this code:

```
clc; clear; close all
[x,y]=meshgrid(-1:.1:1);
e = exp(1);
z=(e^-x^2)+((e^-2)*(y^2))
surf(x,y,real(z));
```

And print this graph:

[image: MatLab]

Why does this difference occur? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one thing, use `exp(...)` Instead of `e^...`, especially if you aren't going to parenthesize properly

Comment: For another, `(e^-2)*(y^2)` needs to be `(e^-2).*(y.^2)`. Notice the dot before the asterisk and caret. Elementwise rather than matrix multiplication and exponentiation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inadvertently performing matrix multiplications when you do `x^2` and `y^2`. To do an elementwise square of the matrices, do `x.^2` and `y.^2`.

Also, while not technically an error, `e=exp(1)` is just overkill when you have `exp` already available.

In sum,

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-1:.1:1);
z=exp(-x.^2)+(y.^2)./exp(2); 
surf(x,y,z);
```

The inputs are all real, so I removed the call to `real`. `./` can be just plain `/` in this case because `exp(2)` is a scalar, but I prefer to be proper.